# zend framework session expires or destroy config settings

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a way to destroy a session on the (Apache) server after for example one hour? Now the session stays in the Apache folder for ever, so each time i start the application the old session is picked (And i don't want that).

```
use Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage;
use Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr;
use Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent;

return [
    // Session configuration.
    'session_config' => [
        // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
        'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60, 
        // Store session data on server for 1 hour.
        'gc_maxlifetime'  => 60*60,
    ],
    // Session manager configuration.
    'session_manager' => [
        // Session validators (used for security).
        'validators' => [
            RemoteAddr::class,
            HttpUserAgent::class,
        ]
    ],
    // Session storage configuration.
    'session_storage' => [
        'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class
    ],

    // ...
];
```

Comment: Your config is correct which means that the server sees the session data as garbage after 1 hour. If the session data isn't deleted then I'm _guessing_ that this is a issue regarding your server setup/config, not Zend.

Comment: Thanks! But it also doesnt see it as garbage, it picks up the old session variables again